# Is it possible for a .Net application to run Gherkin without SpecFlow

Tags: c#, .net, cucumber, gherkin

Part of our Team is migrating from a very bespoke in-house system to BDD-style test suites using cucumber

As part of this migration I would like to create a .Net app that runs cucumber tests, but outputs the results of those tests in a format that they are more used to. Generated nUnit tests via spec flow would be too big a leap, and I'm trying to keep Visual Studio out of the process.

What I'm thinking of is a .Net app written in C# that uses the Gherkin .dll to parse cucumber files and call steps written in C#. The app could then decide how best to display the results of those tests to the user, and run on machines without VS installed.

Is this approach even possible? I've Googled around, and I can't seem to find any examples of anyone doing anything similar (probably because SpecFlow makes things so much easier)

Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on using existing tools as much as possible.  One option would be to use the build process to run the unit tests, then parse the generated output and format it as you like.  Trying to build your own test runner will take much more time than you anticipate.

One comment, focusing on your customer is really the most important thing.  Writing your own tools in house means you then have to maintain them which takes more time away from building value for your clients.  Reformatting the text would probably be your cheapest option.

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather keep the build process out of it, particularly as I don't want a VS dependency. Writing a simple test runner is preferable if that means the app can be stand-alone.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a similar solution!
[is there a way to use .feature file as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966682/is-there-a-way-to-use-feature-file-as-input/28968356#28968356)

I think there should be a way to do it! I think an external gherkin parser and regex operation can be used in an internal tool.  https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin3